# Setting a database to use the Extension Library

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

From a Database I have created and want to create a new Database then copy a number of design elements into it. However, I want to make sure that :
1. That the extension Library is installed?
2. Set the com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library property in the target.
3. What version of the library is installed?

I need to do this because the process will take place on a third parties system, and I will have no control over their configuration, but if it fails to meet a minimum standard I will stop the process and warn the user.

Comment: What exactly is your question? With which language do you want to make these checks? LotusScript, Java, JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point **1** and **3** of your question you can solve with following Java code:

```java
    try {
        String version = com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil.getExtLibVersion();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ExtLib not installed
    }
```

If Extension Library is installed properly then you get the `version`. Otherwise an exception will be thrown and you can handle this case in `catch` block.

If you are developing in LotusScript then put this code into an Java agent and execute it from LotusScript.

For point **2** you have to add the line

```java
xsp.library.depends=com.ibm.xsp.extlib.library
```

to file `WebContent/WEB-INF/xsp.properties`.

Comment: Thanks Knut - as usual!